# nginx locking up when near 3000 active connections

Tags: nginx

nginx main conf:

```
worker_processes  6;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

events {
    worker_connections  10240;


limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=foo:10m rate=2r/s;
limit_conn addr 3;
```

Then inside my domains zone

```
    location / {
limit_req zone=foo burst=100 nodelay;
limit_conn addr 3;
    limit_rate 100k;
    limit_rate_after 1m;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

While the site was frozen shortly after I restarted nginx I saw Active connections / waiting burst to 3000 on nginx_status

```
   location /nginx_status {
        # Turn on stats
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
   }
```

What could be the cause of the site locking up? I have a script running every 60 seconds that reloads nginx which didn't fix it but service nginx restart did. Resource usage during the lock up was near 0% CPU.

Comment: What do the nginx logs show when the situation is active?

Comment: wasn't running error logs at the time but the access logs don't look too bad only 2000 requests in the access log at the time which is normal for our site.

Comment: `reload` only reloads the configuration while `restart` quits the process and therefore kills all connections and vanishes all `limit_rate` buckets.